# Are custom JSP tags accessed by multiple thread

Tags: multithreading, jsp, jsp-tags

I have simple Custom JSP tag defined something like:

```
public class SimpleTag extends TagSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String var;
    private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getVar() {
        return var;
    }

    public void setVar(String var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        populateData();
        pageContext.setAttribute(var, data);
        return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    }

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        pageContext.setAttribute(var, null);
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }

    private void populateData() {
        // add data to "data" map
    }
}
```

I expose the hashmap to the tag body.

Will the tag be reused by the container (caching/pooling) or accessed by multiple threads? Do I need take extra care in the tag design?

I apologize if it's too basic. I've been unsuccessful with my searches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic Tag Handlers could be pooled or not, depending on container;
Simple Tag Handlers could not be pooled, accordingly with the spec (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-eval-spec/JSP2.3MR.pdf)

But anyway, there should not be any threading issue, as a handler is supposed to serve only one request at a time:

> Clarify that a tag handler instance is actively processing only one request at a 
>   time; this happens naturally
>    if the tag handler is instantiated afresh through 
>   new() invocations, but it requires spelling once tag handler pooling is 
>   introduced. This clarification affected Chapter JSP.13.

Answer (score 2):

> Are custom JSP tags accessed by multiple thread

Good answer by user3714601 - indeed tag usage is thread-bound so you shouldn't get any concurrency issues with the design you have posted.

> Will the tag be reused by the container (caching/pooling)

Assume this is possible.  This caused some "interesting" effects on an application I migrated from WebSphere to tomcat a couple of years back.

Clear anything out of the tag instance that may have been left from the previous use before you start working with it. In some environments, this will have no effect but I would recommend something similar to;

```
private void populateData() {
    data.clear();
    // clear anything else you have
    // add data to "data" map
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tags should be instantiated on jsp page rendering per page.They should be request scoped and can contain their own state  and there should not be any thread issues unless you are doing something strange.But to be sure about it, why don't you log the tag class instance id to a log file and do several requests to understand its behavior?